# ajax call without refresh response from alert

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax, to simply update the DB..The problem is that after update, I use a alert to display the output. However when I click the alert box,The entire page reloads. Is there any way to avoid it??

First Up(trailnew.php)- A select drop down button with three button.

When I choose the select drop down button and click edit button

Second- I get a form from aanew.php(with some other things)

Third-Validation of this form is done in aanew.php

Target-I want the success result to be viewed in trailnew.php, without reloads.

Any alternative ideas is highly welcomed..This is new to me..Thanks..

Here is the code. 
Trailnew.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
?>

<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>




 <script>



  $(document).ready(function(){



  $("#form1").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {

    plid:"required",
       },
   messages: {

    plid: "Please select a pack name id..",
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
   ({




type: "POST",
url: "aanew.php",
data: $('#form1').serialize(),
cache: false,

success: function(response) {
    $('#result1').html(response); 

        }
        });
        }

  });




  });



  </script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="result3"></div>
Packing List
</br>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
<?php   


echo '<select  name="plid" id="plid">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select the Pack Name--</option>';
$tempholder = array();
$sql="SELECT CONCAT( p.pl_no,  '_', DATE_FORMAT( p.pl_dt,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) ,  '_', g.acname ) AS plname, g.gl_id,p.pl_no,p.pl_dt,p.no_box,p.pl_id,g.acname FROM packlist p, glmast g WHERE g.gl_id = p.gl_id ORDER BY pl_dt DESC , pl_no DESC LIMIT 30";


$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$nr = mysql_num_rows($query);
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++){
$r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if (!in_array($r['plname'], $tempholder)){
$tempholder[$i] = $r['plname'];
echo "<option value='$r[pl_id]'>".$r["plname"]."</option>";
}
}

echo '</select>';

?><br/>

<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit"/><br/>

</form>
<form>
<input type="submit" name="new" id="new" class="new" value="New" /><br/>
</form>



        <?php
        $e=isset($_POST['form2']) && $_POST['form2'];
if($e)
{
echo "Done";


}
?>  

<div id="result1"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

aanew.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
?>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $("#form2").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {

    plnoedit:"required",
    pldtedit:"required",
    noboxedit:"required",
    glidedit:"required",


       },
   messages: {

    plnoedit: "Please select a pack list id..",
    pldtedit: "Please select a item id id..",
    noboxedit: "Please select a quantity id..",
    glidedit: "Please select a value id..",

        },

         submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
   ({


type: "POST",
url: "trailnew.php",
data: $('#form2').serialize(),
cache: false,

success: function(response) {
    $('#result1').html(response); 

        }
        });
        }



  });

</script>

</head>

        <body>
        <div id="#result1"></div>
        <?php

    $e=isset($_POST['plid']) && $_POST['plid'];
    $f=isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit'];
    if($e&&$f)
    {


    $id=$_POST['plid'];
    $query5=mysql_query("SELECT g.gl_id, p.pl_no, p.pl_dt, p.no_box, p.pl_id,g.acname
        FROM packlist p, glmast g
        WHERE g.gl_id = p.gl_id
        AND p.pl_id ='".$id."'
        LIMIT 0 , 30") or die(mysql_error());

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query5);
    $pl_no=$row['pl_no'];
    $pl_dt=$row['pl_dt'];
    $no_box=$row['no_box'];
    $acname=$row['acname'];



    ?>
        <form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="">
        <P>
            <LABEL for="plnoedit">PackList No 
                      <INPUT type="text" id="plnoedit" name="plnoedit" value= <?php echo $pl_no; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>
                      <input type="hidden" name="myFormsName" value="form5id" id="myFormsName">
            <LABEL for="pldtedit">Date 
                      <INPUT type="text" id="pldtedit" name="pldtedit" value= <?php echo $pl_dt; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>

            <LABEL for="noboxedit">Box No
                      <INPUT type="text" id="noboxedit" name="noboxedit" value= <?php echo $no_box; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>
            <LABEL for="glidedit">Party Name
                      <INPUT type="text" id="glidedit" name="glidedit" value= <?php echo $acname; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>

            <INPUT type="submit" id="editsubmit" name="editsubmit" value="Submit"> <INPUT type="reset">
            </P> 

        </form>
        <?php
        //pagination starts
            $id=$_POST['plid'];
              $per_page = 4;
      $query12=mysql_query("SELECT `pld_id`,`pl_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`, `size`, `potency`, `box` FROM `packlistdtl` WHERE pl_id ='".$id."' GROUP BY `box` ORDER BY `box` desc") or die(mysql_error());
        // figure out the total pages in the database

        $total_results = mysql_num_rows($query12);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        // display pagination

        echo "<p><a href='view.php'>View All</a> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='view.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
        }
        echo "</p>";

        // display data in table
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>Box</th>  <th>Item Name</th> <th>Size</th> <th>Potency</th> <th>Quantity</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
        $item_id=mysql_result($query12, $i, 'item_id');


        $query13=mysql_query("SELECT `item_name` FROM `itemmast` WHERE item_id ='".$item_id."'") or die(mysql_error());

        $row1=mysql_fetch_array($query13);
    $item_name=$row1['item_name'];
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";

                echo '<td>' . mysql_result($query12, $i, 'box') . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' .$item_name. '</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . mysql_result($query12, $i, 'size') . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>' . mysql_result($query12, $i, 'potency') . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>' . mysql_result($query12, $i, 'quantity') . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($query12, $i, 'pld_id') . '">Edit</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysql_result($query12, $i, 'pld_id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        }
        // close table>
        echo "</table>"; 

        // pagination






    }


    ?>



        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Post your code snippet! What is in your AJAX callback function?

Comment: @zavg Posted the code..

Comment: I agree with Orangepill, submit buttons launch the form's action which cause in your case the reload of the entire page.

Comment: @zavg Sorry for late reply..Any alternatives?? If you suggest..Thank you..

Comment: As one of the possible ways, use simple buttons, not submits and attach AJAX actions to them

Comment: @zavg But I need the post value of select drop down list.. Will I be able to access it?? Thank you replying..Will try now.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to return false from click handler of link or button to prevent the default action